# Throwing error in Unit test FormsAuthentication.SignOut()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, httprequest, forms-authentication

While running my unit test method, I am getting error FormsAuthentication.SignOut(). I have mocked the httpcontext like this

```
var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", "");
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer(
    "id",
    new SessionStateItemCollection(),
    new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(),
    10,
    true,
    HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
    SessionStateMode.InProc,
    false);
SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(httpContext, sessionContainer);
var controller = new AccountController();
var requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), new RouteData());
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, controller);
var actual = controller.Login(new CutomerModel() { Login = "admin", Password = "Password1" });
return httpContext;
```

in the login method

```
public ActionResult Login(CutomerModel obj)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

`FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` throws

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. '

Answer (score 5):

The static method `FormsAuthentication.SignOut` is dependent on another static member `HttpContext.Current`, which is not available during unit tests. Tightly coupling your controllers to `HttpContext.Current` which is static results in code that is very difficult to test. Try to avoid coupling to static calls.

Side note: Having difficulty setting up a unit test for your code is a sure sign that it needs to be reviewed and most likely refactored.

Abstract `FormsAuthentication` calls out into their own concerns/interfaces so that they can be mocked.

```
public interface IFormsAuthenticationService {

    void SignOut();

    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

Production code could wrap the actual call which should work as `HttpContext.Current` is then available. Make sure that DI container is aware of how to resolve the dependencies.

```
public class FormsAuthenticationService : IFormsAuthenticationService {

    public void SignOut() {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity

}
```

Refactor the controller to depend on the abstraction and not implementation concerns.

```
public class AccountController : Controller {

    //...other code removed for brevity.

    private readonly IFormsAuthenticationService formsAuthentication;

    public AccountController(IFormsAuthenticationService formsAuthentication) {
        //...other arguments removed for brevity
        this.formsAuthentication = formsAuthentication;
    }

    public ActionResult Login(CutomerModel obj) {
        formsAuthentication.SignOut();
        //...
        return View();
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity.
}
```

And and example test

**Note:** I am using [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) for mocking dependencies and [FluentAssertions](http://www.fluentassertions.com/) for asserting results.

```
[TestMethod]
public void LoginTest() {
    //Arrange
    var model = new CutomerModel() { Login = "admin", Password = "Password1" };        
    var mockFormsAuthentication = new Mock<IFormsAuthenticationService>();

    var controller = new AccountController(mockFormsAuthentication.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = controller.Login(model) as ViewResult;

    //Assert (using FluentAssertions)
    actual.Should().NotBeNull(because: "the actual result should have the returned view");
    mockFormsAuthentication.Verify(m => m.SignOut(), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!